# Is possible to import JIRA User Stories and Acceptance Tests to Robot Framework and link them

Tags: jira, robotframework

I want to import from JIRA; User Stories and Acceptance Criteria as Test Scripts, to Robot Framework.

When I have searched, I Found [JiraRobot Library](https://github.com/NaviNet/JiraRobot).

But this serves the purpose like from robot framework, connect to JIRA, Create issue, assign the user, add the attachment and add a comment.

Please any one help me whether we can import test scripts directly from JIRA to Robot Framework and link these scripts to those user stories for tracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try [jira-cli](https://jira-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This library has the ability to [query JIRA issues](https://jira-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#interacting-with-issues).

Example from docs.

```
  ali@home ~ $ jira-cli view --search-jql 'reporter=ali and type=bug'
```

Reference

1. https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile065/glossary/story
2. https://jira-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#interacting-with-issues

Comment: Hi Shijo, Thanks for your response. using `jira-cli` we can query JIRA issues but how to import the acceptance scenarios in JIRA issue as TestCase to Robotframework?

Comment: As far as I know, it may be difficult, you may have to create your python library for this